# Finding the y intercept in mathematica

Tags: math, command, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a command to find the y intercept for a function in mathematica? I am trying to find all the critical points on the graph of f(x)= (-30 x^3-3x+7+E^(-.001x))/(3x^3-27-3E^(-.001x))

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the y intercept is the value of your function when x is zero, using your function might be helpful.

Comment: What do you call critical points ? Are you looking for the zeroes of a function ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not as precise as you could think.
Critical point is ambiguous.

Let's look at your function (but you should consider using exact fractions in certain circumstances instead of approximate numbers such as .001):

```
f[x_]:=(-30 x^3-3x+7+E^(-.001 x))/(3x^3-27-3E^(-.001 x))

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image: fx]

If what you mean by "y-intercept" is the intersection point between the curve y=f(x)
and the y axis, then this is just

```
f[0]
```

-0.266667

f has only one singular point, where the denominator reaches 0.
It will be a singular point for all of its derivatives.

It is easy to find it :

```
FindRoot[(3x^3-27-3E^(-.001x)),{x,1,5}]
```

{x->2.15428}

Just by looking at it and checking the formula, you can guess that your function is always increasing where defined.

Now, let's look at the derivative

[image: f'(x)]

This confirms monotony.
f' has only one local minimum, at 0.

```
f'[0]
```

0.100007

Now let's plot the second derivative

[image: f''(x)]

It crosses the x-axis at 0 and

```
FindRoot[f''[x], {x, -5, -1}]
```

{x -> -1.69487}

which correspond to the local maximum of f'(x).

The value of f and f' at this point are

```
{f[x], f'[x]} /. %
```

{-3.56742,3.79488}

You can directly ask for this point by using :

```
FindMaximum[f'[x], {x, -5, -1}]
```

{3.79488,{x->-1.69487}}